# Spark merge (replace) on key containing multiple rows

Tags: sql, apache-spark, merge, delta-lake

I am using Apache Spark and I would like to merge two DataFrames, one containing existing data and the other one containing (potential) updates. The merge is supposed to happen on a given number of key attributes, however, for one set of key attributes there will be multiple existing rows that need to be replaced by multiple new rows(if the timestamp of the "update data" is more recent than the timestamp of the existing data).

As a visualization, suppose the existing data is

```
+------+------+---------+-----------+------------+
| key1 | key2 | subkey3 | timestamp | attributes |
+------+------+---------+-----------+------------+
|    1 |    1 |       0 |         0 | something1 |
|    1 |    1 |       1 |         0 | something2 |
|    1 |    2 |       0 |         0 | something3 |
|    1 |    2 |       1 |         0 | something4 |
|    1 |    3 |       0 |         0 | something5 |
+------+------+---------+-----------+------------+
```

and the update data is

```
+------+------+---------+-----------+----------------------+
| key1 | key2 | subkey3 | timestamp |      attributes      |
+------+------+---------+-----------+----------------------+
|    1 |    1 |       0 |         1 | something_new1       |
|    1 |    1 |       1 |         1 | something_new2       |
|    1 |    1 |       2 |         1 | something_new3       |
|    1 |    2 |       0 |         1 | something_new4       |
|    1 |    2 |       0 |         2 | something_even_newer |
|    1 |    4 |       0 |         1 | something6           |
+------+------+---------+-----------+----------------------+
```

then the resulting DataFrame should look like this:

```
+------+------+---------+-----------+----------------------+
| key1 | key2 | subkey3 | timestamp |      attributes      |
+------+------+---------+-----------+----------------------+
|    1 |    1 |       0 |         1 | something_new1       |
|    1 |    1 |       1 |         1 | something_new2       |
|    1 |    1 |       2 |         1 | something_new3       |
|    1 |    2 |       0 |         2 | something_even_newer |
|    1 |    3 |       0 |         0 | something5           |
|    1 |    4 |       0 |         1 | something6           |
+------+------+---------+-----------+----------------------+
```

So the merge, in this case, happens on the two keys `key1` and `key2` and if there are more recent rows for this compound key in the update data, then all existing rows of the same key will be replaced by the latest rows in the update data. Note that the number of rows for a given compound key may change in either direction after applying an update.

One solution to this is a windowed ranking like this:

```
df_merged = ( df_old
  .union(df_update)
  .withColumn("rank",
    rank().over(
      Window.partitionBy(
        col("key1"), 
        col("key2"), 
      )
      .orderBy(col("timestamp").desc())
     )
   )
   .filter(col("rank") == 1)
   .drop("rank")
)
```

What is the most efficient way in Spark to obtain the desired behavior assuming all data is stored in Parquet or Delta Tables?

Comment: can you tell me what happened ```something_new4``` value from the updated dataframe ??

Comment: For (key1, key2) = (1,2), there was data from two timestamps in the update data, of which only the latest will remain.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to solve this with below approach-

### Code

1. #### Read both the dataframe

   **`Dataframe-1`**

```scala
 val implicits = spark.implicits
    import implicits._
    val schema = StructType(
      Array(StructField("key1", DataTypes.IntegerType),
        StructField("key2", DataTypes.IntegerType),
        StructField("subkey3", DataTypes.IntegerType),
        StructField("timestamp", DataTypes.IntegerType),
        StructField("attributes", DataTypes.StringType))
      )
    val data1 =
      """
        | 1 |    1 |       0 |         0 | something1
        | 1 |    1 |       1 |         0 | something2
        | 1 |    2 |       0 |         0 | something3
        | 1 |    2 |       1 |         0 | something4
        | 1 |    3 |       0 |         0 | something5
      """.stripMargin

    val df1 = spark.read
      .schema(schema)
      .option("sep", "|")
      .csv(data1.split(System.lineSeparator()).map(_.replaceAll("\\s*", "")).toSeq.toDS())
    df1.show(false)
    df1.printSchema()
```

Result-

```
+----+----+-------+---------+----------+
|key1|key2|subkey3|timestamp|attributes|
+----+----+-------+---------+----------+
|1   |1   |0      |0        |something1|
|1   |1   |1      |0        |something2|
|1   |2   |0      |0        |something3|
|1   |2   |1      |0        |something4|
|1   |3   |0      |0        |something5|
+----+----+-------+---------+----------+

root
 |-- key1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- key2: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- subkey3: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- attributes: string (nullable = true)
```

**`dataframe-2`**

```scala
  val data2 =
      """
        | 1 |    1 |       0 |         1 | something_new1
        | 1 |    1 |       1 |         1 | something_new2
        | 1 |    1 |       2 |         1 | something_new3
        | 1 |    2 |       0 |         1 | something_new4
        | 1 |    2 |       0 |         2 | something_even_newer
        | 1 |    4 |       0 |         1 | something6
      """.stripMargin

    val df2 = spark.read
      .schema(schema)
      .option("sep", "|")
      .csv(data2.split(System.lineSeparator()).map(_.replaceAll("\\s*", "")).toSeq.toDS())

    df2.show(false)
```

Result-

```
+----+----+-------+---------+--------------------+
|key1|key2|subkey3|timestamp|attributes          |
+----+----+-------+---------+--------------------+
|1   |1   |0      |1        |something_new1      |
|1   |1   |1      |1        |something_new2      |
|1   |1   |2      |1        |something_new3      |
|1   |2   |0      |1        |something_new4      |
|1   |2   |0      |2        |something_even_newer|
|1   |4   |0      |1        |something6          |
+----+----+-------+---------+--------------------+
```

## Approach-1 (Recommended)

- Create `struct<timestamp, attribute, subkey3>`
- Group by `key1` and `key2` and use collect all struct elements
- Get `max(struct<timestamp, attribute, subkey3>)`
- Fetch individual elements

```scala
val processedDf1 = df1.unionByName(df2)
      .withColumn("timestamp_attributes", struct("timestamp", "attributes", "subkey3"))
      .groupBy("key1", "key2")
      .agg(max("timestamp_attributes").as("attributes"))

    processedDf1.show(false)

    processedDf1.selectExpr("key1", "key2",
      "attributes.subkey3 as subkey3", "attributes.timestamp as timestamp", "attributes.attributes as attributes")
      .show(false)
```

Result-

```
+----+----+----------------------------+
|key1|key2|attributes                  |
+----+----+----------------------------+
|1   |1   |[1, something_new3, 2]      |
|1   |2   |[2, something_even_newer, 0]|
|1   |3   |[0, something5, 0]          |
|1   |4   |[1, something6, 0]          |
+----+----+----------------------------+

+----+----+-------+---------+--------------------+
|key1|key2|subkey3|timestamp|attributes          |
+----+----+-------+---------+--------------------+
|1   |1   |2      |1        |something_new3      |
|1   |2   |0      |2        |something_even_newer|
|1   |3   |0      |0        |something5          |
|1   |4   |0      |1        |something6          |
+----+----+-------+---------+--------------------+
```

## Approach-2

2. #### Find the latest value for each group order by timestamp

   - Create `struct<timestamp, attribute, subkey3>`
   - Group by `key1` and `key2` and use collect all struct elements
   - sort the elements by timestamp and fetch the latest element
   - select the individual field from struct

```scala
 val processedDf = df1.unionByName(df2)
      .withColumn("timestamp_attributes", struct("timestamp", "attributes", "subkey3"))
        .groupBy("key1", "key2")
      .agg(collect_list("timestamp_attributes").as("attributes"))
      .withColumn("attributes", element_at(array_sort(col("attributes")), size(col("attributes"))))

    processedDf.selectExpr("key1", "key2",
      "attributes.subkey3 as subkey3", "attributes.timestamp as timestamp", "attributes.attributes as attributes")
      .show(false)
```

Result-

```
+----+----+-------+---------+--------------------+
|key1|key2|subkey3|timestamp|attributes          |
+----+----+-------+---------+--------------------+
|1   |1   |2      |1        |something_new3      |
|1   |2   |0      |2        |something_even_newer|
|1   |3   |0      |0        |something5          |
|1   |4   |0      |1        |something6          |
+----+----+-------+---------+--------------------+
```

> Please note that if there are huge number of attributes for a group by key, then I would suggest **not** to use `collect_list` since you might face resource crunch on the executors

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Comparing my desired result with your result, some of the attributes of (key1, key2) = (1,1) are missing, though. Also, the number of rows for a given key might actually be in the realm of 100,000 or more, which is why I am looking for a very efficient method.

Comment: First row of the result is (1,1) , no?

Comment: If you want consider `subkey3` in the grp, add it in the group by and remove from the struct.

Comment: Edited my answer with `Approach-1` and `Approach-2`. I believe `Approach-1` is an efficient way. please use that. accept + upvote, if it helps you

Comment: Please look at my example for what the output should look like. For one combination of `key1`,`key2`, the data of the latest timestamp should be kept (including all `subkey3` values falling into that bucket). In the example case, that means that there should be 3 rows for `(key1, key2) = (1,1)` in the result.